# Как настроить реконект к nats на golang

Tags: golang

пишу **pub-sub** сервис на **golang** с брокером **nats**,
Мне необходимо настроить бесконечный реконнект в моём приложении. Часть кода приведена ниже.

```
func main(){
 go ReadNats()
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
    <-c
}

func ReadNats() {
    var err error
    durable := "backend"
    stanCon, err  := stan.Connect("ibis",uuid.NewV4().String(),stan.NatsURL("nats://172.16.16.250:4222"),stan.SetConnectionLostHandler(func(sc stan.Conn, reason error) {
        fmt.Println("Connection lost, reason:", reason)
        for reason != nil {
            sc, reason = stan.Connect("ibis",uuid.NewV4().String(),stan.NatsURL("nats://172.16.16.250:4222"))
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    }))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cant connect")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Connected")
    }
    sub, err := stanCon.QueueSubscribe("event","", func(msg *stan.Msg) {
        mes := generator.Msg{}
        json.Unmarshal(msg.Data, &mes)
        fmt.Println(mes)
    },stan.StartAtTimeDelta(time.Minute*10),
        stan.DurableName(durable),
    )
    if  err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(sub.ClearMaxPending())

    signalChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    cleanupDone := make(chan bool)
    signal.Notify(signalChan, os.Interrupt)
    go func() {
        for {
            for range signalChan {
                fmt.Printf("\nReceived an interrupt, unsubscribing and closing connection...\n\n")
                if durable == "" {
                    sub.Unsubscribe()
                }
                stanCon.Close()
                cleanupDone <- true
            }
        }
    }()
    <-cleanupDone
}
```

проблема в том, что приложение отказывается корректно реконнетиться спустя какой-то промежуток времени, то есть если nats упадет и поднимется в течении первых  ~10 секунд, то всё пройдет успешно, но потом реконнект вроде как пройдет тоже, но сообщения уже приходить не будут.

Библиотеки для взаимодействия с nats, которые я использую:

"github.com/nats-io/stan.go"

"github.com/satori/go.uuid"

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в количестве реконнектов.

Период реконнекта и количество попыток задаются при получении соединения. Если они не указаны явно, то есть дефолтные значения:

```
    Default Nats Connection Constants
    const (
        Version                 = "1.9.1"
        DefaultURL              = "nats://127.0.0.1:4222"
        DefaultPort             = 4222
        DefaultMaxReconnect     = 60 - здесь меняется на оч большое число
        DefaultReconnectWait    = 2 * time.Second
        DefaultTimeout          = 2 * time.Second
        DefaultPingInterval     = 2 * time.Minute
        DefaultMaxPingOut       = 2
        DefaultMaxChanLen       = 8192            // 8k
        DefaultReconnectBufSize = 8 * 1024 * 1024 // 8MB
        RequestChanLen          = 8
        DefaultDrainTimeout     = 30 * time.Second
        LangString              = "go"
    )
```

Видно что дефолтных значений хватит на 2 мин отсутствия соединения.

Чтобы исправить ситуацию надо просто запросить больше реконнектов:

```
import (
    nats "github.com/nats-io/nats.go"
    stan "github.com/nats-io/stan.go"
)

bigInt := 1<<63 - 1 // очень большое число
nc, err := nats.Connect(natsURL, nats.MaxReconnects(bigInt))
nsc, err := stan.Connect(clusterID, clientID, stan.NatsConn(nc))
```